# Help modelling silicone baby fork (lumpy surfaces, lose of details, adjusting measurements of pins)

Tags: modeling, topology

[image]

I've been struggling for over a week trying to model something I thought would be simple.  It's a silicone baby fork.  The client keeps sending it back as I cannot get it quite right.  In my attempts to make corrections, mostly using proportionate editing, the fork as now lost some details such as the curve that sort of forms a bowl on the inner part of the fork.  How do I recreate that?

The measurements of the forks pins are incorrect and I can't figure out the best way to adjust it.  I think I'm close but I need to somehow square off the pins so that they are .5 cm thick.

On top of that, the bowl part of the fork is no longer smooth, now it's lumpy.  I've tried smoothing vertices, I've tried using relax in loop tools, smooth modifier almost works, but then I loose details on some edges.

[image]

If there is an addon that can help me with all this, I'll buy it.

Any other tips would be greatly appreciated!  I have less than 3 days to complete the project.

Here's some other photos that may help:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to start over and use a non-destructive workflow. Although, imo, this is a task for a CAD software.

Comment: Have you got a reference for the depth of the spork? The thickness is, strictly speaking, not enough info, you don't know the external curvature in depth.

Comment: Yes, I have all the measurements (I think), but they were given to me one at a time.  At first it was just the length and the width, then I got measurements for the overall height, then I got measurements for the thickness of the fork head in several areas, how deep it is, etc.  I've had to start over a few times, and I'm trying to keep from starting over again if I can help it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should keep it low-poly as long as you're not glad with the general shape, then give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and only apply the modifier when everything's ok (but always keep a low-poly version).

I would stick to the shape from top view. Make sure that the edges follow the shape so that it will be easy to add edge loops further on:

[image]

Use the *Proportional Editing* option to curve the spoon (hide the part that you don't want to deform):

[image]

Then extrude up:

[image]

Move down the outer edges:

[image]

Then add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, add edge loops or bevels to sharp some angles, etc...

Comment: It the client is happy moonboots should get paid for this one.  ;-)

Comment: haha yeah, I feel like this is still quite a few polys though. I'd imagine the reflections don't look too great, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @susu, thanks....  ;)

Comment: @HISEROD, yes it's very low poly but it's the hardest part, once you're good with this it's easy imho

Comment: @moonboots I think you misunderstood, I thought it looked a little too _dense._ usually when you have a lot of faces on a relatively large curved portion, you get lumpy reflections (coming from a car modeler so I'm super picky lol).

Comment: @susu I have been practicing and watching tutorials.  I tried a few of his products before being hired, and they were good, it's just this particular one along with a few others have been quite difficult for me.  I've approached the problem several different ways, and I'm reaching a deadline, and just do not know the best approach to fix this.  I just needed some additional help.

Comment: no problem, I hope it helps  ;)

Comment: @moonboots - you make it look so easy!  It helps to see your topology.  They say to start with a shape that most reflects a part of the model, so I had started with a subdivided square, squished it down and deleted the top half, to sort of form the bowl of the spork.  I think tried modeling everything else around that.

Comment: @moonboots - thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There must be several ways to do it, the one I've used can be very convenient